# Using Processing in Android Studio is giving a memory leak

Tags: android, android-studio, memory-leaks, applet, processing

Please be kind - I'm new!

I'm using Processing in Android Studio via PApplet (As per the Processing example detailed here: https://android.processing.org/tutorials/android_studio/index.html)

In Android Studio, I have 2 activities (MainActivity and Screen2) where clicking a button in MainActivity calls Screen2. From Screen2 I want to be able to hit the phone's back button to return to MainActivity.

Ok, it does work ...but according to the Android Profiler, I have a memory leak and sure enough with repeated opening and closing of Screen2 (Eventually) I get an out of memory error and the app crashes.

I've checked Google, StackOverflow etc and am aware of the onStop and onDestroy methods and the lifestyle of activities and fragments but I'm obviously not using them properly as I can't stop the leak (I got nowhere so haven't even included these methods here)

Here are the contents of the Class files:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


public void jump(View v){
   Intent i = new Intent(this, Screen2.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

(I'm calling the jump method via the onClick attribute of a button in activity_main.xml)

**Screen2.java**

```
package com.example.test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import processing.android.CompatUtils;
import processing.android.PFragment;
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Screen2 extends AppCompatActivity {

private PApplet sketch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);
    frame.setId(CompatUtils.getUniqueViewId());
    setContentView(frame, new 
ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    sketch = new mySketch();
    PFragment fragment = new PFragment(sketch);
    fragment.setView(frame, this);
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
if (sketch != null) {
sketch.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, rantResults);
}
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
if (sketch != null) {
sketch.onNewIntent(intent);
}
}
}
```

**mySketch.java** (The Processing file)

```
package com.example.test;

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class mySketch extends PApplet {

public void settings() {
fullScreen(P3D);
}

public void setup() {
textSize(40);
fill(0);
}

public void draw() {
text("Hello from Processing",100,100);
}
}
```

Android Profiler says the leak is in the Java so my feeling is that although the Screen2 activity is being closed, the Processing sketch's fragment isn't. Do I need to use FragmentManager for this (Still beyond me at the moment) or is there an easy way to close the Processing fragment and release the memory properly at the same time that the Screen2 activity is closed? (I only have 1 fragment)

Thank you for any help...

Simon

Comment: Show your PF fragment please

Answer (score 0):

[Pardon me, I wanted to say these as a comment but for my current reputation I can't and moreover no one else is answering your question and as I have analyzed the samples and your code, I am sharing these as an answer]

After researching both your code and the two samples provided in the link of yours 'Processing for android', this is the conclusion and hopefully will help you guide to finding accurate answer:

The updates of dependencies of your code might be problematic or may be you are using old versions of dependencies but using updated formats of code. Another thing is I don't get it why you need to change activity, simply implement your code in the main activity and see what happens. My suggestion will be to you, after you gather enough knowledge about Processing then try and add more activities and check performance issues.

Analyzing the two sample codes, they are running smoothly in my Emulator and creating no 
memory leaks, and the PFragment of the PApplet is built-in code so, there is little a chance of errors but not impossible. So, my best guess is that the dependencies of the PFragment might be problematic. Try changing the dependencies by adding "*implementation files('libs/processing-core.jar')*" which can be found from sample code ex2_fragments_sv4 "*dir:app/libs/processing-core.jar*".

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't make a comment either (Rep<50, not sure why they do that?) but thanks for getting back to me.

A good suggestion with the dependencies but yes, I am up to date.

As for the multiple activities, yes it seems pointless with this example but I've written a bigger app (With a much bigger Processing sketch) and am seeing a memory leak of around 50Mb per cycle of the second activity.

Rather than have everybody wade through that needlessly, I recreated the problem on this smaller scale - hence the rather pointless example you see here. Yes, the example code appears to run smoothly here too and the memory leak I'm getting with the example code is only around 2 Mb but it's still a memory leak so very infuriating...

I have been writing Processing sketches in Android Mode for a few years but only in the stand-alone Processing IDE. I'm new to using Processing in Android Studio so am sure it's something I'm doing wrong with the fragment.

Simon

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the problem. 2 separate ones actually...

I'll close the question but include my thoughts in case it helps someone else...

First, the simple one: What I thought was an (admittedly small) leak (ie 1 - 2Mb) in the above code actually wasn't a leak at all. Being new to Android Studio (And Android developing generally) I noticed in Android Profiler that my memory used was constantly creeping up and took this to be a leak. If I'd had more patience and waited that bit longer then I'd have seen the Garbage Collector do its thing and recover the memory that I thought I'd lost.

What have I learnt? The need for patience! Memory no longer being used isn't always tidied up immediately in Android and this doesn't mean you have a leak.

And now for the bigger one: The example code above was simply to replicate a much bigger leak (about 50Mb each time I opened and closed a 2nd activity) in a more complicated project involving Processing, PApplets and fragments. Initially I thought that the basic code above was recreating the same leak but on a much smaller scale (My reason for including it here) but actually this was just a red herring.

The real reason for the 50Mb leak was one of static variables. I'd declared a PApplet object as static in the launcher activity (Intending it to have app-wide scope) then imported this into my second activity where I used it to instantiate a Processing sketch and tied the sketch to the activity using PFragment. Well, on closing the 2nd activity, it was this PApplet object (Declared in the launcher activity, instantiated in the 2nd activity) that remained in memory and caused the problems.

Simply moving the PApplet declaration to the 2nd activity so that it could be properly cleared up by the GC cured all the memory leak problems.

Thanks to all who took the time to help...

Simon